# Do any philosophers talk about dying alone?

Tags: death

Do any philosophers talk about dying alone, what it means or even how do so well?

In the example, the dying person may have some people that could visit (it's not a sudden death), but chooses to exclude them for what they did - or may have done - previously, before he was dying. Allow a stranger, then, to be watching.

Comment: is this a really inauthentic question lol?

Comment: not a philosopher per se, but famous quote from Orson Wells, "We're born alone, we live alone, we die alone."

Comment: ha nice quote @thesilentcartograher not necessarily bitter sweet, idk